# Is there a clever way to underline a heading?

Tags: vim, macvim

This isn't a particularly important, but it's something I've been curious about for a while.

I write a lot of documentation using rST (Sphinx).  This is how you write a heading:

```
My Awesome Heading
==================

Lorem ipsum dolor...
```

I'm wondering if there's a clever way in vim to do that underline, rather than just rapidly pressing the equals key a dozen times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
" underline current line
yypVr=
```

Comment: A bit shorter: the default behavior for Y is the same as yy.

Answer (score 4):

```
:t.|s/./=/g
```

One keypress shorter than [Barton's solution](https://superuser.com/a/692059/176100). ;)

Comment: thx, this is going to my vimrc.

Comment: Shifting is a keypress. You tied. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
yyp
:s/./=/g
```

This copies and pastes the current line, then substitutes '=' for each character.

You can wrap this a macro or set up a function within .vimrc